# Why isn't there a link to the moderator tools in the menu bar?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

I recently hit the 10K privilege of [mod tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), and I'm wondering why there isn't a link in the toolbar at the top to the moderator tools. Is there supposed to be?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moderation tools are really the review queue - except you have single action in some cases rather than needing collaborating votes to take action.

I have 10k on StackOverflow and my toolbar looks like yours when there are no items needing moderation / review. When the edit queue goes to 0 its number disappears, and the same with the flag queue.

[image]

Based on your screenshot, I suspect that Ask Different's 10k people keep up with the requests (and continue to do so when you look), so the 10k tool queue is empty.

To get the 10k moderation tools, first choose review and choose Tools or bookmark this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged

[image]

Comment: Mark is correct, the 10k flags are seldom non zero.  Anyone can bookmark the admin tools - http://apple.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged but they don't become useful until you have acces to them.

Comment: Ah okay. So http://apple.stackexchange.com/tools doesn't show up in the toolbar.